# resize rename and rotate multiple images using Python

Tags: python, rotation, resize, rename

I have a Python code challenge - I have a `source_image` folder containing several image files. There are no sub folders
I need to make following changes and save the converted files in the `target_image` folder:

- The images that are there in the source_image folder are in wrong format, in .tiff format this need to be converted to .jpeg format
- Image resolution in the `source_image` folder is set to 192x192 pixel this need to be converted to 128x128 pixel
- Image in the source_image folder is rotated, files needs to be rotated 90° counter-clockwise.

After implementing above changes, save modified files in the target_image folder
I tried following code. It did not give me any error, but did not created any files in the target folder. I am wondering what did I do wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

    from PIL import Image
    import os, sys

    def resize_rename_rotate(srcfile, targetdir="", size=(128,128)):
        targetfile = os.path.splitext(srcfile)[0]
        extension = os.path.splitext(srcfile)[1]

        if srcfile != tgtfile:
            try :
                 im = Image.open(srcfile)  # open file
                 im.rotate(90) # degrees counter-clockwise
                 im.resize((128, 128)) # resize the file
                 im.save(targetdir+targetfile+extension,"jpeg")
            except IOError:
                print ("cannot change image for ", srcfile)

    if __name__=="__main__":
        targetdir = "../output/"
        srcdir = "../input/"

        for file in os.listdir(srcdir):
             resize_rename_rotate(file,targetdir)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found following things with this code:

1. rotate and resize image like this :

   ```
       im = im.rotate(90) # degrees counter-clockwise
       im = im.resize(size) # resize the file
   ```
2. The `srcfile` argument for `Image.open(srcfile)` is just the filename and not the complete path of source image. I think you should provide the complete path as argument like this :

   ```
   im = Image.open(srcdir+srcfile)
   ```
3. I changed the extension like this:

   ```
   im.save(targetdir+targetfile[0]+".jpeg")
   ```

After these changes, the following code worked for me ( tested it on .tif images):

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys

def resize_rename_rotate(srcdir,srcfile, targetdir="", size=(128,128)):

  #srcfile_path : the complete path to source file
  src_path = srcdir+srcfile

  targetfile = os.path.splitext(srcfile)
  extension = os.path.splitext(srcfile)[1]
     
  if srcfile != targetfile:
     try :
         im = Image.open(src_path)  # open file
         im = im.rotate(90) # degrees counter-clockwise
         im = im.resize(size) # resize the file
         im.save(targetdir+targetfile[0]+".jpeg")
     except IOError:
         print ("cannot change image for ", srcfile)

if __name__=="__main__":
  targetdir = "./target_pics/"
  srcdir = "./src_pics/"

  for file in os.listdir(srcdir):
     resize_rename_rotate(srcdir,file,targetdir)
```

I hope it works for you!